# In vue.js is it possible to notify "observers" to refetch the value from the observed data, without changing the value of the observed data

Tags: vue.js

Suppose that I have an input element bound like this:

```
<input :value="somedata">
```

The user types something in the input, and since I am not using `v-model` or altering `somedata` through a handler, the value of the element is now different from `somedata`. This is what I want, but I would also like to have the following capability:

Without changing the value of `somedata` I would like to be able to notify the element so that it sets its value equal to `somedata` again. Something like knockout's `notifySubscribers()` or `valueHasMutated()`

Is that possible in vue.js?

**UPDATE: A clear illustration of the issue here:** https://jsfiddle.net/gtezer5c/3/

Comment: Can you elaborate the use case, when do you want to notify the elment and set its value equal to `somedata`.

Comment: @saurabh suppose the user types something in the input and at some point the changed event is fired. Now suppose that the decision or not to update the underlying data with the new input.value is determind asynchronously. If the decision is YES, then I can go on and set the observed property with the new value from the input. But what if the decision is NO and I want to revert the input's value back to the value of the observed property, which has not changed.

Comment: So, in short, you don't want to update the actual values until all the temporary values have a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult interpreting what exactly the requirements and acceptance criteria might be to suit your needs, and I thought Bill's solution was what you were after, but after all the updates and clarifications, I think I understand a little more what you're trying to accomplish: in short, I think you need a generic way to have an input that can hold a value but that can be independently reverted to some other value.

Please have a look at [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmRgQV?editors=1011). I believe it's providing what you're trying to do. It allows you to create an `input` element as a `revertable` component, which can optionally be passed a default value. Any changes to that input are maintained by the component with its `value` data property. It will not be observing/pulling in any `lastKnownGood` type of value because any reversion will be pushed into the component from outside.

Externally to the `revertable` component, you can `$emit` a `revert` event with a new value that will cause either all `revertable` components or a single `revertable` component (with a matching ID) to be reverted.

I feel like it's mostly a clean solution (assuming I'm understanding the requirements correctly), except that in VueJS 2 we have to use a standalone, shared Vue object to pass the events when there is no parent-child relationship. So you'll see:

```
const revertBus = new Vue()
```

defined in global scope in the demo. And the `revertable` component will use it to receive incoming messages like so:

```
revertBus.$on('revert', (value, id) => { ... }
```

and the controlling Vue object that is triggering the messages will use it like this:

```
revertBus.$emit('revert', this.reversionValue, targetId)
```

You can also emit the event with a `null` value to cause the `revertable` component to reset its value to its initial default value:

```
revertBus.$emit('revert', null, targetId)
```

Again, it's a *mostly* clean solution, and though it might not fit perfectly inline with what you're trying to accomplish, I'm hoping it might at least help you get closer.

Comment: Yes, it is a solution that fits and I will mark it as accepted as obviously vue doesn't provide a facility to "notify subscribers" to re-load a value. This is how I had it in my project before, but I felt that creating a component just for this is too much, that's why I posted the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm following properly but I'll give it a shot.

What I think you want is to only update some values when their "temporary" values meet some type of condition. Here's how I was thinking of it.

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="tempValues.one">
  <input v-model="tempValues.two">
  <input v-model="tempValues.three">

  <pre>{{ values }}</pre>
  <pre>{{ tempValues }}</pre>
</div>
```

Then, in my component, I watch `tempValues` and only update `values` when a condition is met.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    values: {
      one: '',
      two: '',
      three: '',
    },
    tempValues: {},
  },
  created () {
    // Create the tempValues based on the real values...
    this.tempValues = Object.assign({}, this.values)
  },
  methods: {
    updateValues (tempValues) {
      // Only updating the values if all the tempValues are longer than 3 characters...
      var noneEmpty = Object.values(tempValues).every((value) => value.length > 3)
      if (noneEmpty) {
        this.values = Object.assign({}, tempValues)
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    // Watch tempValues deeply...
    tempValues: {
      handler (tempValues) {
        this.updateValues(tempValues)
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
})
```

Here's a quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/ja50tenf/

Comment: Your fiddle led me to consider binding the input to the temporary values, but my example was just trying to show the use case. Let me explain: I want to be able to one-way bind some data to an input, (i.e. whenever the data changes, the input sets its value) and do nothing when the user types stuff in the input. But I also want to be able to revert the input's value back to the data, without having a reference to the input as I might want to do that outside from any event handler on the input. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/gtezer5c/3/

Comment: I see now. That isn't what I got from the original question at all. I'd probably use a `watch` instead: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/gtezer5c/4/

Comment: A quick update to that to show how the data is behaving: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/gtezer5c/5/

Comment: Ok, but what about if there are more than one components "observing" lastknowngoodstuff? : I need an explicit value property for each one, as well as a change in the revert method for each one. So unless I am missing something, the method you propose is worse than holding a ref and updating the element directly( with $refs I dont have to introduce the "value" properties). But the point is I want to make the revert method totally independent from whatever observes the data property. Do you think I am totally missing something here? If not is it worth posting a feature request?

Comment: Also, in my fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/gtezer5c/3/ ), note a very important property: If I just paste in the html a new input element or any simple or complex component and bind it to the lastknowngood stuff property and an input emitter, I dont have to touch the js code. Look for example here: https://jsfiddle.net/gtezer5c/6/ . I just added the select element. It works with no change at all in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourvar.__ob__.dep.notify()
```

works on objects and arrays

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should be able to do this with help of `v-on:input`. You can call a function on `input` and put your logic of checking and updating in this function:

```
<input :value="somedata" v-on:input="yourMethod">
```

In fact if you look at the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events), `<input v-model="something">` is syntactic sugar on:

```
<input v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">
```

so instead of assigning variable `something` to value inputted, you can put your logic in that place.

Comment: I know that, in fact I already have a handler using change event (not input event, as I dont want to calc for each stroke), which does assign the element's value (event.target.value) to a temporary reactive data property. But see my edit for why this doesn't work for me